# Calculating the area between 2 functions (one of which is a difficult piecewise function)

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I am having a problem with computing the area between a simple function and a complicated one: I need to compute the area between $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}x& 0\le x < \pi/2 \\ \pi-x &  \pi/2 \le x \le 3\pi/2 \\ x-2\pi& 3\pi/2\le x\le 2\pi\end{cases}$. The area should be calculated in $0 \le x \le 2\pi$.

I don't know how to solve it and compute this monsetrous integral with $g(x)$.

Comment: Did you try graphing them?

Comment: of course, but i still don't know even how to solve it. should i calculate it as 3 different integrals? or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Yes, as three different integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Break it into three integrals, one from $0$ to $\pi/2$; the next from $\pi/2$ to $3 \pi/2$, and the last from $3\pi/2$ to $\pi$. Then each integral is easy.

Comment: can you please tell me how much did you get in the end? i want to verify if i did correctly

Comment: I didn't actually do the integral; instead, I answered the question in a way that I thought might help you learn to do problems like this.